# Transform columns by a list (map) of functions

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a named list of functions, where the `names(transform_functions)` correspond to the column names and the functions are the transformations to be applied to every specific column. For example, in the example below, `transform_functions$height` is `function(x) x+1`,  so I expect the equivalent outcome of `starwars |> mutate(height = height + 1)`.

In total, this should do the equivalent of `starwars |> mutate(height = height + 1, birth_year = birth_year / 2)`

Is there a non-cluttery way to write this? `reduce2` works as shown below, but it seems I must be reinventing something here. `across` is not it, as it applies a specified set of functions to *multiple* columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

transform_functions <- list(
  height = function(x) x+1,
  birth_year = function(x) x/2
)



# This works, but is hardly readable and seems like a lot of hassle
purrr::reduce2(
  .x = transform_functions, 
  .y = names(transform_functions),
  .f = function(df, fun, col) 
    df |> mutate(!!col := fun(!!sym(col))),
  .init = starwars)

# Obviously doesn't work, since it would assign (rather than execute) the function to each column 
starwars |>
  mutate(!!!transform_functions)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you convert/wrap your `transform_functions` into unevaluated expressions, you can splice them into a `mutate` call:

```
transform_expressions = transform_functions |>
    imap(\(f, n) bquote(.(f)(.(as.name(n)))))
```

```
starwars |>
    mutate(!!! transform_expressions)
```

This becomes especially convenient if you can directly encode the expressions, rather than having to convert them from functions:

```
transform_expressions = alist(
    height = height + 1,
    birth_year = birth_year / 2
)
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `imap_dfc()` and an `across()` call:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

starwars %>%
  mutate(imap_dfc(transform_functions, ~ across(all_of(.y), .x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
starwars |>
  mutate(across(names(transform_functions), ~ transform_functions[[cur_column()]](.x)))
```

Mhm. I don't like `cur_column()` but I guess it works